# Why is the contains method returning false when it should return true?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am implementing a function that closes a div on click anywhere in the document except the clicked div.

I am using the useRef hook by assigning a ref to the target div/login modal. It should not close the target div/login modal when I click inside of it but it is happening this way.

The console shows that the contains method is returning false, meaning that the place I clicked is not contained in the target div so that is why it is closing when I click anywhere inside of it. When the clicked element(event.target) is actually contained inside the target div and it should return true.

This function worked fine in other project but in this one it is not.

The function:

```
function closeOnAnywhereClick(ref) {
      useEffect(()=>{
        function handleClickOutside(event){
          if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)){
            console.log(ref.current, event.target, ref.current.contains(event.target))
            setLoginMethodsModal(false)
          }
        }
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
        return () => {
          document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside)
        }
      },[ref])
  }

  closeOnAnywhereClick(toCloseOnAnywhereClick);
```

Here is a picture of the console, it shows that the event.target is actually contained in the ref.current element but the method is returning false:
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5eiY.png)

I only checked for wrong syntax in my code because this snippet was already implemented and working well in my other project. Nothing could have been done as I was not able to find any reasonable mistake.